# Message: Undefined property: Register::$load

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

> Message: Undefined property: Register::$load
>
> Filename: controllers/Register.php
>
> Line Number: 7
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\v\application\controllers\Register.php Line: 7
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\v\index.php Line: 316 Function: require_once

This is the controller

```
class Register extends MY_Controller 
{ 
    function __construct() 
    { 
        //  parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->model('m_register');   
    } 
    function index()    
    { 
        $this->load->view('secure/register_page'); 
    } 
}
```

This is the Model

```
class M_register extends CI_Model 
{ 
    function tambah_registerbaru($noktp,$nama_kons,$alamat,$nohp) 
    { 
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");  
        $dt = array( 'noktp' => $noktp, 'nama' => $nama_kons, 'alamat' => $alamat, 'telp' => $nohp, 'dihapus' => 'tidak' ); 
        return $this->db->insert('pj_pelanggan', $dt); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you please show how you are loading model file?

Comment: class M_register extends CI_Model 
{
 
 function tambah_registerbaru($noktp,$nama_kons,$alamat,$nohp)
 {
  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta"); 
  $dt = array(
   'noktp' => $noktp,
   'nama' => $nama_kons,
   'alamat' => $alamat,
   'telp' => $nohp,   
   'dihapus' => 'tidak'
  );

  return $this->db->insert('pj_pelanggan', $dt);
 }
}
class Register extends MY_Controller {
 function __construct() {
 // parent::__construct();  
  $this->load->model('m_register');   
 }
 
  function index() {
  $this->load->view('secure/register_page');
 }

}

Comment: Please try to run with parent construct uncommented.
function __construct() 
    { 
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->model('m_register');   
    }

Comment: Please let me know whether that solved your issue or not. Thanks